# How do I make a media Query responsive in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, media-queries

I really need some help with media queries. I have made a testimonial slider and when it gets to a 800px breakpoint, I want to disable the JS for the slider and change the layout.

The problem is that I am unable to deactivate the js once it has been activated, I'm not sure if the problem is from the event handler, the if statement of from the deactivation function.

I have managed to deactivate the JS but I have to reload the page to do it, I want it to be responsive so that I don't have to reload the page every time.

If you can help, that would be a huge help, thanks!

Here is my JS code:
(All my css code works, hence, it hasn't been added).

```
const mQ = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 800px)');

const testimonialSlider = function () {

  const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
  const btnLeft = document.querySelector('.slider__btn--left');
  const btnRight = document.querySelector('.slider__btn--right');
  const dotContainer = document.querySelector('.dots');
  const testimonialContainer = document.querySelector(
    '.testimonial-outer-container'
  );

  //Deactivate functions

  const deactivateJs = function (slide) {
    slides.forEach(
      (s, i) => (s.style.transform = `translateX(${0 * (i - slide)}%)`)
    );
    testimonialContainer.removeChild(dotContainer);
    console.log('DeactivatingJs');
  };
  // Activate functions
  const activateJs = function () {
    console.log('ActivateJS');
    let curSlide = 0;
    const maxSlide = slides.length;

    //Functions

    const createDots = function () {
      testimonialContainer.appendChild(dotContainer);
      slides.forEach(function (_, i) {
        dotContainer.insertAdjacentHTML(
          'beforeend',
          `<button class="dots__dot" data-slide="${i}"></button>`
        );
      });
    };

    const slideReady = function () {
      createDots();
      activateDot(0);
      goToSlide(0);
    };

    const goToSlide = function (slide) {
      slides.forEach(
        (s, i) => (s.style.transform = `translateX(${100 * (i - slide)}%)`)
      );
    };

    // Activate dots
    const activateDot = function (slide) {
      // First we remove the active class on all of the dots and then we add it to the one that it is active
      document
        .querySelectorAll('.dots__dot')
        .forEach(dot => dot.classList.remove('dots__dot--active'));
      document
        .querySelector(`.dots__dot[data-slide="${slide}"]`)
        .classList.add('dots__dot--active');
    };

    // Next slide

    const nextSlide = function () {
      if (curSlide === maxSlide - 1) {
        curSlide = 0;
      } else {
        curSlide++;
      }
      goToSlide(curSlide);
      activateDot(curSlide);
    };

    const prevSlide = function () {
      if (curSlide === 0) {
        curSlide = maxSlide - 1;
      } else {
        curSlide--;
      }
      goToSlide(curSlide);
      activateDot(curSlide);
    };
    slideReady();

    //Event Handlers

    btnRight.addEventListener('click', nextSlide);
    btnLeft.addEventListener('click', prevSlide);

    // Creating an event with the arrows
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
      console.log(e);
      if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft') prevSlide();
      if (e.key === 'ArrowRight') nextSlide();
    });

    dotContainer.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      if (e.target.classList.contains('dots__dot')) {
        /// const slide = e.target.dataset.slide;
        //This is the same as above, the slide part is from the html and the dataset is an HTML attribute
        const { slide } = e.target.dataset;
        goToSlide(slide);
        activateDot(slide);
      }
    });
  };

  // if (mQ.matches) {
  //   deactivateJs();
  // } else {
  //   activateJs();
  // }

  const js = function () {
    if (mQ.matches) {
      console.log('deactivate');
      deactivateJs();
    } else {
      activateJs();
    }
  };
  mQ.addEventListener('change', js);
};

testimonialSlider();
```

Comment: Have you try to delete event listener? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Comment: Thanks for the tip Buggies. I still can't manage to get it to work using the removeEventListener.

Comment: I tried the following syntax but it didn't fix the problem:                                               
 !mQ.addEventListener('change', activateSlider);
mQ.removeEventListener('change', activateSlider);